# How can I not delete the client when I open the modal?

Tags: reactjs

When a user deletes a client, I have created a modal that asks the user(Are you sure you want to delete it).
The problem is as soon as the modal is open, the client is deleted, even though the user has not clicked yes to confirm the delete.

ClientList.js

```
export default function ListClients() {
 const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState();
 const [userlist, setUserlist] = useState([]);

   function deleteClient() {
       const userParams = {
          clientName:
        clientName,
          country: country,
          clientid: selectedID,
        };
        
       axios
          .delete(process.env + "client", {
        data: clientParams,
          })
          .then((response) => {
        setClientlist(clientlist.filter((client) => client.id !== clientId));
          })
          .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
          });

  // const openModal = () => { 
  //   setShowModal(prev => !prev);
  // };


  }

return(
     <div>
    <tbody>
        {userlist.length > 0 ? (
           userlist.map((userlist) => (
             <tr key={userlist.id}>
                <td>
                  <div">
                      {userlist.id}
                   </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" onClick={() => {deleteClient(clientlist.id); setShowModal(true)}}> 
                      Delete
                  </button>
                 </td
             </tr>
        </tbody>

         //the idea is to pass the  state for modal to show 
<ModalDelete showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} onDel={() => deleteClient(clientlist.id)}/>

      </div>
);
```

ModalDelete.js

```
export default function ModalDelete({ showModal, setShowModal,onDel }) {
 
return(
  <div>
    { showModal ? <Transition.Root show={showModal}>  
       <div>
       <p> Are you sure you want to delete the client?</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => {onDel(); setShowModal(false);}>Yes</button>

        <button type="button" onClick={() => {setShowModal(false);}} >
            Go Back
         </button>

          </div>
    </Transition.Root> : null }
  </div>
);
}
```

When the user clicks yes in the modal, I want the client to be deleted.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `deleteClient` function in the event handler assigned to the delete button, before setting `showModal` to `true`. This causes the client to be deleted first and the modal to be displayed afterwards.

To fix this, you should update the event handler to not call `deleteClient`. Instead, define a function in the `ListClient` component which will close the modal and call the `deleteClient` function. Pass this as the `onDel` prop to your `ModalDelete` component.

(Edit: Fixed grammar)

Comment: ```userlist.id```  is from the for loop, which I can use it in a function above...